# Parameterized query with NOW() function call

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I am creating a parameterized MySQL query in C#. I need to pass the `NOW()` function in this query, but I cannot figure out how to do this.

This is part of my code:

```
MySqlParameter param = new MySqlParameter();
param.Value = field[1];
param.ParameterName = field[0];
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
```

If I pass `NOW()` as a parameter this does not work.

Comment: Going with JW's answer below will mean that the local server time will be inserted into the database. If you specifically wanted the current date/time on the client machine to be inserted instead, you could have passed `DateTime.Now` to the parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can't parameterized `NOW()`, however, just insert it in your query, eg

```
string myQuery = "INSERT INTO tableName (col1, col2,) VALUES (@val1, NOW())";
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, you solved my problem. This explains why I couldn't find any way to do this.